# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar el sistema si borré /bin/bash?

Tags: bash, raspbian

El otro dia trasteando con la Raspberry borré sin querer el fichero `/bin/bash`, por lo que ahora no puedo hacer nada que necesite del shell de Bash, ni siquiera acceder por ssh.

He probado a reinstalar Bash pero me dice que ya esta instalado, por lo que no lo instala y con la opción `--reinstall` obtengo un error.

No sé si hay alguna manera de arreglar esto sin tener que reinstalar el sistema operativo, que en este caso es Raspbian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como se ve en [How to recover from a deleted /bin/bash?](https://serverfault.com/a/451530/200076):

Si tu `/bin/sh` no apunta a `/bin/bash`, entonces puedes crear un enlace simbólico:

```
ln -s /bin/sh /bin/bash
```

Esto hará que cuando el sistema intente buscar Bash, se encuentre con sh, que es la consola genérica y comparte bastante funcionalidad. Al menos te permite moverte un poco por allí y realizar el comando importante:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash
```

Que lo que hace es reinstalar Bash en tu sistema.